# Flutter : Replace LaunchUrl with WebView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterwebviewplugin, url-launcher

Within my flutter app, I am launching a payment gateway using the `url_launcher` plugin with opens the page in a browser. However I would rather have it open in a `WebView` plugin instead, within the app.

Do I need to use both? how can implement such.

Please assist

**Url launcher**

```
if (selectedPaymentMethod == 'Pay Now' &&
                                      _formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                                    () async {
                                      final ozowApiRes = await OzowApiProvider()
                                          .createPaymentRequest(
                                        'R${(cart.totalAmount + cart.serviceFee + value * cart.newCylinderPrice).toStringAsFixed(0)}',
                                        userData?['username'],
                                        userData?['phoneNumber'],
                                        userData?['email'],
                                      );
                                      () async {
                                        try {
                                          await launchUrl(
                                            Uri.parse(ozowApiRes.data),
                                          );
                                        } catch (ex) {
                                          throw 'Could not launch $ozowApiRes';
                                        }
                                      }();
                                    }();
```

Comment: why do you use WebView,? why don't you use url_launcher via unilinks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you can use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) or [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview). I will recommend you to use flutter_inappwebview if possible cause url_launcher `100% not guaranteed` you to launch in inAppWebView and also flutter_inappwebview gives you the granular controll in a page.

(1) you can use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) with mode `LaunchMode.inAppWebView`

```
await launchUrl(
  Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/"),
  mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView,
);
```

(2) or you can use a stateless widget page with [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) and just pass the purchase url

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

class InAppPurchasePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const InAppPurchasePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Purchase Page"),
      ),
      body: InAppWebView(
        initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
          url: Uri.parse(
            "https://flutter.dev",
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```